# WPF Combobox when SelectedValue is 0 then the Combobox should not select

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, selectedvalue

I have a combobox in a WPF application with MVVM implemented. It looks like, -

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboParent" 
              SelectedValuePath="FileId"
                  DisplayMemberPath="FileName"
                  IsEditable="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"
                  MaxDropDownHeight="125"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedFile.ParentFileId}"
               SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedParentFile, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="26"/>
```

The **Files** collection is having a self referential key as **ParentFileId**. Now sometime this ParentFileId would be zero; meaning there is no parent file. In that case, I would expect that though the dropdown will have all the files but there will not be any SelectedItem.

But in reality am getting the **SelectedFile** as the SelectedItem in the ComboBox.

Can I get the ComboBox without anything selected when the ParentFileId is zero?

(I do not want to add any placeholder File in the collection of Files with FileId as zero.)

Comment: Just a thought. Why don't you make the reference nullable ? then instead of zero it will be null.

Comment: Actually, the way the current implementation is this self referential key is not null. In places where there is no mapping it is having the value zero. Hence that is not an option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the explanation why this doesn't work out of the box:

`SelectedValue` is returning a `null` value when `SelectedItem` is also `null`. Your `ParentFileId` property is an integer (I guess) which doesn't support `null` values, and it has no way to know how you'd want to convert from `null` to an integer value. So the Binding throws an error, and the value remains unchanged in your data.

You need to specify how you want to convert those null values with a simple **Converter** like this:

```
public class NullToZeroConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.Equals(0))
            return null;
        else
            return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return value;
    }
}
```

Add it as resource to your view:

```
<Grid ...>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:NullToZeroConverter x:Key="nullToZeroConverter" />
        ...
    </Grid.Resources>
    ...
</Grid>
```

And then use it in your `SelectedValue` Binding:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboParent" 
          SelectedValuePath="FileID"
          DisplayMemberPath="FileName"
          IsEditable="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"
          MaxDropDownHeight="125"
          Validation.Error="cboParent_Error"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedFile.ParentFileID,
                                  Converter={StaticResource nullToZeroConverter}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedParentFile, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Height="26"/>
```